# how to truncate labelname using authoryear-style?

Tags: biblatex

I've got a problem with my labelname in the bibliography. I adapted authoryear-style in order to display labelname and labelyear at the beginning of a reference. I want to display a maximum of two authornames (last names). If there are more than two authornames it should display the first authorname and add "et al.". Maybe it should be a counter like maxlabelnames=2... At the moment the labelname is truncated after only one authorname.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, firstinits=true, uniquename=init,  backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{
\iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{\printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}~
            \printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}\\}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{and={\&}}

\begin{filecontents}{Label.bib}
@book{Bogelsack.1985,
author = {B{\"o}gelsack, G. and Kallenbach, Eberhard and Linnemann, Gerhard},
year = {1985},
title = {Roboter in der Ger{\"a}tetechnik},
address = {Heidelberg},
publisher = {A. H{\"u}thig},
isbn = {3778510428}
}


@book{Warnecke.1990,
author = {Warnecke, H.-J and Schraft, R. D.},
year = {1990},
title = {Industrieroboter: Handbuch f{\"u}r Industrie und Wissenschaft},
address = {Berlin [etc.]},
publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
isbn = {3540509348}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{Label.bib}

\begin{document}

Test (\cite{Bogelsack.1985}). 

Test 2 (\cite{Warnecke.1990}).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The Bögelsack-item is okay, but the Warnecke-item is wrong. It should be:

**Warnecke & Schraft 1990**

Warnecke, H.-J.; Schraft, R. D. (1990): Industrieroboter: Handbuch für Industrie
   und Wissenschaft. Berlin [etc.]: Springer-Verlag. isbn: 3540509348.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Did you try setting `maxnames=2` instead of `maxcitenames=2`? This sets `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` and this latter is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to define a new specification for printing names.

First of all we create a counter to store the value of how many names (at most should be printed in the label).

```
\newcounter{maxlabelnames}
\setcounter{maxlabelnames}{2}
```

Then we define a novel format

```
\DeclareNameFormat{biblabel}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listtotal}>\themaxlabelnames}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
      {#1 \bibstring{andothers}}
      {}%
    }
    {
      \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
        {#1}
        {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
          {\multinamedelim #1}
          {\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace#1}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

Finally the new format is used in the `begentry` hook

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{\printnames[biblabel]{labelname}~%
            \printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}\\}
```

With `maxlabelnames=2` the output is

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help! I knew that you have to create a novel format, but I don't know all the commands, for example  \ifthenelse or where I have to use which command. I'm still a beginner :)

Comment: There might even be a predefined format/macro in biblatex, but it was faster to write it than looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s `introcite` feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2, giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  introcite=plain,]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\newline}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bogelsack.1985,
  author    = {Bögelsack, G. and Kallenbach, Eberhard and Linnemann, Gerhard},
  year      = {1985},
  title     = {Roboter in der Gerätetechnik},
  address   = {Heidelberg},
  publisher = {A. Hüthig},
  isbn      = {3778510428}
}
@book{Warnecke.1990,
  author    = {Warnecke, H.-J and Schraft, R. D.},
  year      = {1990},
  title     = {Industrieroboter: Handbuch für Industrie und Wissenschaft},
  address   = {Berlin [etc.]},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  isbn      = {3540509348},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite{Bogelsack.1985}

Test 2 \autocite{Warnecke.1990}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bögelsack et al. 1985//Bögelsack, G.; Kallenbach, E.; Linnemann, G. (1985). Roboter in der Gerätetechnik. Heidelberg: A. Hüthig. isbn: 3778510428.////Warnecke & Schraft 1990//Warnecke, H.-J.; Schraft, R. D. (1990). Industrieroboter: Handbuch für Industrie und Wissenschaft. Berlin [etc.]: Springer-Verlag. isbn: 3540509348.]

Answer (score 0):

The correction for that is to replace the `\renewbibmacro{begentry}` from Guido with the following:

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{\printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}~
            \printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}
            \qquad }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question here, but to your own question that you posted as an answer. Please, have a look at our [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to learn about how this Q&A site works.